# Function:boolean for type cheking inside if statement not getting recognize as valid typecheck

Tags: typescript, if-statement, types, boolean

TLDR: How can I make my own typecheck function that returns a boolean, or any other way that I can archive checking both 'instanceof' at once.

Im making a simple calculator. and
I have the next working function for the first number assignment, be in mind that all variables are strings and that's intended, and not the problem on topic:

```
function asignOperand(e: Event){
    if (e instanceof MouseEvent &&
        e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement &&
        e.target.dataset.key &&
        operator === '' && preOperandB === ''){

        preOperandA += e.target.dataset.key;
```

and I wanted to wrap all that long if statement inside another functions that returns a Boolean. Because that check is repeated another time elsewhere in the code. Like so:

```
function checkOperandsType(e: Event){

 if (e instanceof MouseEvent &&
        e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement &&
        e.target.dataset.key &&
        operator === '' && preOperandB === ''){

        return true

 } else return false
}
```

but when making it so:

```
function asignOperand(e: Event){
    if (checkOperandsType(e)){
        preOperandA += e.target.dataset.key;
} }
```

I get `'e.target' is possibly 'null'` and `Property 'dataset' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'` .

So what is the proper way for shorter / best practice / intended way of type checking?